# How to make google maps show in english

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I have Gmail and all language settings I could find there are set to US English.
However, when I type "googlemaps" in my search bar and click on the link https://maps.google.com/‎ it will show me the map in Arabic language which I can not read. Does anybody know what I need to do in order to set it back to English?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this that do not require logging in to a Google account.

1. Cookies: Go to `google.com/ncr`. This will set a cookie in your browser saying that you want to view the US English version of Google. This will apply to all google services such as Maps until you clear cookies.
2. Query strings: You can also just append `?hl=en` to the end of the URL. For example: `maps.google.com?hl=en`. If you want to do it this way, it's worth reading about how query strings are formatted since you might run into issues if one is already in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found it out myself. I share to maybe allow someone else with the same annoying problem to save some valuable time of his life.
First I went to this page: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2539428?hl=en&rd=1
Point 1 holds a link to Search Settings which I clicked. Now with me, this new page rendered in Arabic. I had to click around until I found some language selections with radio buttons. There I selected english and saved with the blue shaped button. After that, finally no more Arabic. HTH

Answer (score -3):

Just log in to your Google account. Click the 'Log In' blue button at your upper left. It should solve the problem, if you've saved English as you preferred language.

Comment: Yes, this will solve the problem, but the problem is - it is not safe to logon into google account everywhere. Specially if you are in foreign place.